# Groovy and Hydro with same catkin workspace

Tags: catkin, ros-groovy, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello folks,

Easy question. I know that I can install Groovy and Hydro at the same time on my computer since they are going to be installed on different folder in `/opt`. I know I need to source differently depending on which distribution I'm using but can I use the same `catkin_ws` for Hydro and Groovy at the same time or do I need to have two different workspace  like `catkin_ws_groovy` and `catkin_ws_hydro` for example ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/140746/groovy-and-hydro-with-same-catkin-workspace/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since a catkin workspace captures the workspace that it was built on top of as part of the build process, you'll need to have two separate workspaces.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-20**:
Just as a note: You might want to use symlinks in your src folder to only have one common checkout of your code for both workspaces.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Note that you might not necessarily be able to run any Groovy program on Hydro (Hydro program on Groovy) but assuming it does, you'd need to build it with your target installation sourced. To clarify, an example where your package is in the directory ~/catkin_workspace:

Every time you want to switch installations you'll need to do all of these:

```
source /opt/ros/groovy/setup.bash or source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash
cd ~/catkin_workspace
rm /devel -r
rm /build -r
catkin_make
source devel/setup.bash
rosrun my_package do_cool_stuff
```

Note that you need to remove /devel and /build (actually probably just /devel, but I'm not sure about that one) because it contains references to the current installation, ie it is Groovy or Hydro specific.

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-03-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-20**:
you will not want to remove `/build` and `/devel`, those are folders in the root of your file system. I dearly hope you don't have/need those folders and they are user readable. The command is `rm -r build` (no leading slash). `build` will be the more important one to remove (contains build

**Comment by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on 2014-03-20**:
configuration referencing the underlay), but if you must, remove both to be sure. Note that creating workspaces is so cheap that it is much easier to just have two.